# UI Cutomization for Binaries to View in Staging and Active

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions, binary

I'm following the Bart blog https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/view_in_staging_live.aspx UI customization for the pages to view the page in staging and active it is working.

I'm trying to implement the customization for the Binaries.
For binaries what need to be passed `ItemType`? in the JS and for selecting item as Page using `ItemType.PAGE`.

```
Tridion.ContextMenus.STAGING.prototype._isAvailable = function (selection, pipeline) {
    var items = selection.getItems();

    if (items.length != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    var itemId = selection.getItem(0);
    var item = $models.getItem(itemId)
    if (item) {
        if (item.getItemType() != $const.ItemType.?????) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (pipeline) {
        pipeline.stop = false;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Our use case is that we are using Binaries as DCPs and we will have a configuration component mapping the location of the binaries to the Structure group which will be used for forming the URL

Any help appreciated thanks

Comment: Bart's extension resolves pages to their urls. For Multimedia Components you'll need to handle two scenarios for when the binary is published directly as part of a Dynamic Component Presentation or when it's used in content or a page. I think this will be more than just changing the ItemType--especially since the binary may be used in multiple locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binaries are simply Components (or Multimedia Components if you will), so they will have `ItemType.COMPONENT`.

This however doesn't help you much, you can extend the JavaScript to check if the Component is a Multimedia Component, but I'm not sure if you need to load the item for that (if you need to, you can't do that in the `isAvailable` check).

Furthermore, viewing a binary on your website is not something you can simply do, since the binary is published using the `AddBinary` command, which will have determined its exact location. So depending on your template code, that could differ for each binary (in general they are mostly published to the Publications Images location, but theoretically it could be any Structure Group).

So to make this work, you will either have to make asumptions (which might be wrong in which case you can't find your binary) or require a lot of knowledge about the binary.

What might be a better option is to upgrade to SDL Web 8, since there you have the [View on site](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-F2E8EAC0-16B7-409B-BA90-02BA4A02CB2D) option (when you use the new Publishing Model via Business Process Types and the Topology Manager), which works for both Pages and Components (including Multimedia Components)